Get name from enum in pure C
I wish to get name from enum by number. Code similar to this:
enum Fruit {
  Apple,
  Banana,
  Peach,
};

printf(Fruit[1]);


Expected result should be 'Banana'

I found examples for C++ and other languages but I need them for C.
In example are just 3 values in enum, but in real there are many of them and it's error prone if I need to type them more than one time. I didn't find a solution to deal it with that in C.
Edit 23.Oct. at 9:00 GMT
Just to explain little more what I needed.
Example program:
    enum modes{
    mIdle,
    mStop,
    mGoStop,
    mStarDelay,
    mDeltaDelay,
    mInDelta,
};


if (Mode==mIdle) {}
if (Mode==mStarDelay) {}
if (Mode==mDeltaDelay & SomeOtherConditions) {}


if (GotError){
    printf("!ERROR: Got error X at %i\n", Mode);
}

There are multiple if (Mode==..) and this need to be fast so I can't use strings instead. But when I hit some error condition I wish to print in text not as number.

Add an array of strings with the names, and use the enum value as an index into it. You can also encapsulate it into a function.

If you only want to write the values once, X-Macros are a good choice.

as wohlstad sugessted I temporary I use python script parsing source to generate array of strings from enums. It works perfectly but wish to be done without external program.

Never use printf like that. The first argument must always be a string literal. Like printf("%s", my_text)

You could do that using so called X-macros.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define X_GEN_ENUM(name) \
  name,

#define GEN_ENUM(name, X) \
  enum name { X(X_GEN_ENUM) }

#define X_GEN_TOSTR_FN(name) \
  case name: return #name;

#define GEN_ENUM_TOSTR_FN(fn, name, X) \
  const char *fn(enum name e) { switch(e) { X(X_GEN_TOSTR_FN) }}

#define X_GEN_FROMSTR_FN(name) \
  else if(!strcmp(s, #name)) { return name; }

#define GEN_ENUM_FROMSTR_FN(fn, name, X) \
  enum name fn(const char *s) { if(0) {} X(X_GEN_FROMSTR_FN) else { assert(0); } }

This is how you could use these macros:
#define X_FRUIT(X)      \
  X(Apple             ) \
  X(Banana            ) \
  X(Peach             ) \


GEN_ENUM(Fruit, X_FRUIT);
GEN_ENUM_TOSTR_FN(Fruit_tostr, Fruit, X_FRUIT);
GEN_ENUM_FROMSTR_FN(Fruit_fromstr, Fruit, X_FRUIT);




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  enum Fruit n = Fruit_fromstr("Banana");

  printf("%d\n", n);
  printf("%s\n", Fruit_tostr(n));

  printf("%s\n", Fruit_tostr(0));
  printf("%s\n", Fruit_tostr(1));
  printf("%s\n", Fruit_tostr(2));
}


This seems to work but indeed I need to rewrite every line where I used enum parameter. I won't change entire program. I look only for addition that in one place can output as string. Seems that in C is not doable in easy way. Will stuck with additional array generated from source.

If you do that there might be a little shortcut, by using designated initializers. Just in case you didn't know.
const char *names[] = {   [Apple] = "Apple",   [Banana] = "Banana",   [Peach] = "Peach", };

What you are looking for is an array, not an enumerator.
Enumerators are used for accessing a number representation of a constant value.
You can't access it directly backwards.
https://www.w3schools.com/c/c_enums.php
https://www.codecademy.com/resources/docs/c/enums
You should use instead a char array like this:
const char *fruitNames[] = {
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Peach"
};

printf("%s", fruitNames[1]);

If you insist on using integer values to access the enum value, you can use X-Macros in the preprocessor.

No. I need enumerator. Only on one place (log reporting) I wish to print name instead a number.

I edited original question so should be more clear now.
